# extra list element is created while creating list of xts in a loop in R

Tags: r, list, loops, merge, xts

I am trying to create a list of xts objects using a loop:

```
x <- list()#creating list of xts
#n is number of columns, n is 13
for(i in 1:n-1)
{
  x[[(paste0("cor_BG_", i))]]<-as.xts(dcccor[1,i+1,])
  }
#binding all correlation pairs together
combined.xts <- do.call("merge.xts", x)
```

The last line merges all xts files like cor_BG_0,cor_BG_1,cor_BG_3.....up to cor_BG_12. The problem is my loop is supposed to generate xts files with the first element cor_BG_1, As n should be 1 as per the loop for first iteration. However, it is generating the xts cor_BG_0 without passing n=0 in the loop. I am not able to understand how this extra xts is generated and how one can get rid from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1:n-1` returns `(1-1):(n-1)` - that's where the 0 is coming from.

What you need is `1:(n-1)`.

Comment: Dear @Milan Valášek many thanks for the help. It is working. But why the code itself do (1-1)? any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome! It's just how the `x:y - 1` syntax is evaluated. You meant `x:(y - 1)` but R read it as `(x:y) - 1`.

Comment: @gauravkumar: I would strongly recommend you start the habit of using `seq()`, `seq_len()`, `seq_along()`, etc to create the iterator in `for` loops. Those behave correctly in the edge case when `n = 0`, where the `1:(n-1)` pattern would iterate for `i = c(1, 0, -1)`.